# exec command works in terminal not with PHP

Tags: php, exec

I'm writing a class who let me access to **recutils** through PHP.

I have a 'database' file called books.rec in ../database/ and a script who runs my Recutils.php class.

My class simply launch system application with correct parameters.

But When I try to use `recins` with PHP's `exec` function, the command doesn't work will it work in command line.

This is the command that is executed by my script :

`recins -f Title -v "Moi" -f Author -v "Moche" -f Location -v "loaned" -t Books ../database/books.rec`

With PHP : Nothing, the record is not inserted (no error message at all too).
In terminal : OK, the command is well done and my record is inserted.

I also have a method to do a *select* operation using `recsel` and it works very well, will it use exactly the same file (and runs from `exec` too).

So, could someone explain me why the command don't work will another with the same file work ?

Thanks

PS : Further informations : http://www.gnu.org/software/recutils/

Comment: Does www-data have permissions to run command line utilities?

Comment: Did you try to use `exec` second parameter to get output ? (exec will only return last line). And be aware that `../database/books.rec` will be relative to your php script

Comment: @tandu3 : Yes www-data have the permission, because I do the same thing in the same script with `recsel` and it works perfectly.
@soju : Yes I use the second parameters and it is empty. books.rec is accessible because I use it in the same script perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would double check that you are running the command as the same user from the command line and your php script. That may be the problem. `exec('whoami')`

You said you had a script that starts your php script it should be the same user as that.

You might also want to running a simpler exec command to see if that will work first.

Other things to try:

1. Try checking stderr output `exec('ls /tmp 2>&1', $out);` This will redirect standard error to standard out so you get both.
2. Try using php's `shell_exec()` which will invoke a shell just like when you are running from the command line(eg. bash). `shell_exec('ls /tmp 2>&1 >> /tmp/log')` should even put all output into a log file.
3. I don't think this will help you but it is something to try if all else fails, set it as a background process and see if it completes. `exec('nohup php process.php > process.out 2> process.err < /dev/null &')`. The & will set the command to run in the background and let the script continue.

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you very ! using `shell_exec('ls /tmp 2>&1 >> /tmp/log'` I have been able to see that permissions were denied (with the other methods, I still don't have any return string). In fact I completly forgot to change right on my project (project is in ~/www and not in /var/www). Will I was able to read my file I don't understood that I was not able to write in. In was not a problem in excution writes but in writing rights.

Answer (score 0):

Is `recins` command accessible for PHP ? Also is path to `books.rec` correct ?
Try with absolute path.

Comment: Yes `recins` is in my $PATH (as `recsel`) if suppose that if I can run `recsel` I can run `recins` (they where installed the same way and the same time). And yes path to books.rec is correct (I use it in the same script perfectly).