# node command run from php returns status code 1

Tags: php, node.js, command-line, exec

I have php 7.3, nginx, ubuntu 22.04, and have this php:

```
$cmd = 'LD_PRELOAD="/var/www/localhost/node/so/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 /var/www/localhost/node/so/libssl.so.0.9.8" /var/www/localhost/node/node /var/www/localhost/node/nodejs-highcharts.js /tmp/201c0374305c6a74d019739c0f519a9d';
$output = exec($cmd, $out, $retval);
file_put_contents('/tmp/output.txt', 'output: [' . print_r($output, true) . "]\n\nout: [" . print_r($out, true) . "]\n\nretval: [" . print_r($retval, true) . "]\n\ncmd: [" . $cmd . ']');
```

When I run that exact command on the command line, it produces an svg with no issues. However, when the same command is run from php, I get this:

```
output: []

out: [Array
(
)
]

retval: [1]

cmd: [LD_PRELOAD="/var/www/localhost/node/so/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 /var/www/localhost/node/so/libssl.so.0.9.8" /var/www/localhost/node/node /var/www/localhost/node/nodejs-highcharts.js /tmp/74d8fe466d722be67ef78c606c3e5d37]
```

- I thought it might be a permissions issue, but I changed all the
  files in the node folder to have the user "www-data" and a mode of
  775. nginx is running with the "www-data" user.
- I'm not sure what the return code of "1" indicates.
- I don't get any PHP errors.
- it appears that when php tries the exec() command the node file doesn't even fire at all. The first line of the the nodejs-highcharts.js writes a text file to show that it's running, and it doesn't get written when run from php. It does write the file when run from the command line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5155316/5300921 "debug" it this way?

Comment: Exec only captures stdout, and the program might be complaining into stderr. By default PHP will put that where it puts its own stderr, which is usually the web server's error log file. Aside from that you can add `2>&1` to the command which redirects stderr to stdout so you can capture it with that command, but it will mingle with the usual output of your program if you leave it there afterwards.

Comment: If you want to be able to control the I/O streams more directly look at using [`proc_open()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open) instead.

Comment: @Sammitch Adding the "2>&1"  to the end of the command was incredibly helpful! I can now see the error that was occurring. If you like, please add that as the answer.